# why to set Layout to null in index page when using Jquery TableSorter

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, layout, razor, tablesorter

I am trying to use Jquery Tablesorter for sorting and paging of my MVC 4 razor index page .But doing so i found that i have to set Layout=null in the page , why is that ? 
By doing this i am not able to preserve my Master Layout design .

Thanks

Binaya Acharya

Comment: Why do you have to set `Layout = null`? Could you show your code and explain what exactly are you trying to achieve and what problems are you encountering?

Comment: HI @DarinDimitrov , actually i am practicing MVC4 , here in any index page , the jquery method do not work until i set Layout=null in that particular page.

Comment: @Binayacharya JQuery method should work even you have Layout="some_layout". Where did you put the jquery script reference? put the script reference in the layout page and set Layout="your_Layout" in other pages. This is very basic..